# Android: screen tilted other fontsize

Tags: android, fonts

If my screen get's tilted my font goes beyond my button's borders.

How can I define a different fontsize depending on screen orientation ?

I now have my button defined as such:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonred"
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the same style in `res/values/styles.xml` and `res/values-land/styles.xml`.  Make the font size in one of them different.

Comment: Thanks, I know it's considered a shopping question, but is there any good reading on all this stuff? Because I think in a good basic guide these things would be covered no?

Comment: Apologies for the boilerplate response -- this is something I sent to a developer yesterday:  To begin writing apps, first go to the Developer Guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/) and read the articles under Android Basics.  Then go to Resources (http://developer.android.com/resources/) and complete the Tutorials.  Once you have done that, you are ready to start experimenting.  In the Eclipse IDE, you can create new Android projects based upon the Samples. Build and run a couple of these, then modify them as you wish.